# Defining Gauss-Kronecker curvature for submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$ and relation with ${\rm d}{\bf N}_i$'s

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I'm trying to find a definition for Gauss-Kronecker curvature of submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$, but I'm only finding it for hypersurfaces. I would like to know if someone knows any text which works in $\Bbb R^n$, but not kicking it and going all out for manifolds. (I'm self-studying this). I also have some ideas, which I would like to know if are in the right way.

Let $M^k \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a oriented submanifold. Let $\{{\bf e}_1, \cdots, {\bf e}_k\}$ and $\{{\bf N}_1, \cdots, {\bf N}_{n-k}\}$ be orthonormal bases for the tangent and normal spaces, respectively.

- The second fundamental form at the point ${\bf p} \in M, {\rm II}: T_{\bf p}M \times T_{\bf p}M \to (T_{\bf p}M)^\perp$ can be defined by: $${\rm II}({\bf v},{\bf w}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-k} -\langle {\rm d}{{\bf N}_i({\bf v}),{\bf w}}\rangle {\bf N}_i.$$
- Since $\{{\bf e}_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is an orthonormal basis, we define the trace of ${\rm II}$ by $${\rm tr}({\rm II}) = \sum_{i=1}^k {\rm II}({\bf e}_i,{\bf e}_i).$$
- So we define the mean curvature vector by: $${\bf H} = \frac{1}{n}{\rm tr(II)}.$$

Here my problem begins. I'm trying to base myself in this part of Kühnel's Differential Geometry: Curves - Surfaces - Manifolds, in page $118$:

[image]

- I'm tempted to define the Gauss-Kronecker curvature as: $$K = \frac{\det_{\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle}({\rm II})}{\det({\rm I})}.$$
  But this notion of $\det_{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$ does not seems precise enough for me. This bothers me, because if the dimension of the submanifold is greater than $2$, what would be taking the "product" of three vectors? (the "product" of two vector is simply their inner product).

But what is in favor of this definition is the following: in $\Bbb R^3$, we have one shape operator $\mathcal{S}_{\bf N} = -{\rm d}{\bf N}$. Here, with codimension $n-k$, we will have $n-k$ shape operators related to the initial fixed base: $$\mathcal{S}_{{\bf N}_1} = -{\rm d}{\bf N}_1, \ldots ,\mathcal{S}_{{\bf N}_{n-k}} = -{\rm d}{\bf N}_{n-k}.$$
I made a few examples in $\Bbb R^4$, which seems to indicate that: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\det(-{\rm d}{\bf N}_i) = \frac{\det_{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}({\rm II})}{\det({\rm I})}.$$
Since in $\Bbb R^3$ we have $K = \det(\mathcal{S}_{\bf N})$, it would be natural to define $K$ as this sum, at least for $n=4$.

A final remark: I do not want a definition which uses principal curvatures. I want a definition that I can use safely in Lorentz-Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^n_1$ (there are timelike surfaces with no principal directions).

I'm sorry for the long post, but I really need some pointers here, and I wanted to share my efforts with you. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: This might already be equivalent to one of your definitions but for me a natural definition would be the following: Define the G-K curvature to be a function of unit normal vectors. For each unit normal vector $\nu$, the second fundamental form is a symmetric matrix $\nu\cdot \mathrm{II}$ with respect to an orthonormal basis of tangent vectors. Define the curvature at $\nu$ to be $K(\nu) = \det (\nu\cdot\mathrm{II})$.

Comment: Hi Deane, thanks for the comment. I'm not familiar with the notation $\nu \cdot {\rm II}$, and I understood the following: If we write ${\rm II}({\bf e}_i,{\bf e}_j) = \sum_k h_{ij}^k {\bf N}_k$, if $\nu = {\bf N}_k$, the matrix $\nu \cdot {\rm II}$ would have as entries the $h_{ij}^k$? I quite expected the G-K curvature to be a number which didn't depended of the direction I took.

Comment: I don't see any way to define the Gauss-Kronecker curvature as a single number. Only as a function of the normal vector.

Comment: You could take the average value over all unit vectors.

Comment: It is something to be considered, thanks. Is my understanding of $\nu \cdot {\rm II}$ right?

Comment: Yes, you have it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible reason for you to be having trouble finding the 'right' definition of Gauss-Kronecker curvature is that you haven't really told us what properties you want this curvature to have.   I gather that you want it to be a scalar that is a function of the second fundamental form somehow and that, in the hypersurface case, it should be the classical Gauss-Kronecker curvature, which, in the hypersurface case, is defined as the ratio of the $\mathbf{N}_1$-pullback of the volume form on $S^{n-1}$ (where $\mathbf{N}_1:M\to S^{n-1}$ is the (oriented) Gauss map) to the induced volume form on $M$.

The natural way to generalize this is to generalize the Gauss map.  In other words, for an oriented manifold and frame field as you have defined it above, consider the mapping
$$
^\ast\gamma = \mathbf{N}_1\wedge \mathbf{N}_2\wedge\cdots \wedge\mathbf{N}_{n-k}: M\to \mathrm{Gr}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
or, what, by duality, is essentially the same thing, the *generalized Gauss mapping*
$$
\gamma = \mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2\wedge\cdots \wedge\mathbf{e}_{k}: M\to \mathrm{Gr}_{k}(\mathbb{R}^n),
$$
where $\mathrm{Gr}_{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ means the Grassmannian of oriented $p$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a homogeneous space of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ of dimension $p(n{-}p)$ and which carries a natural $\mathrm{SO}(n)$-invariant metric, $h$.

Then one natural definition of a scalar $S$ is to take the ratio of the volume form of $\gamma^*h$ to the induced volume form on $M$.  Up to a sign, this reduces to the Gauss-Kronecker curvature when $k=n{-}1$ (i.e., the hypersurface case).  The formula in terms of the coefficients of the second fundamental form is then
$$
S = \sqrt{\det(H_{j l})} \qquad\text{where}\qquad 
H_{jl} = \sum_{\alpha, i} h_{\alpha i j}h_{\alpha i l}
$$
where the index $\alpha$ satisfies $1\le \alpha\le n{-}k$ and the latin indices satisfy 
$1\le i,j\le k$.

Another natural scalar that is well-defined when $k=2$ or $k=n{-}2$ and $n$ is even is to note that $\mathrm{Gr}_{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\mathrm{Gr}_{n-2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ both carry a canonical $\mathrm{SO}(n)$-invariant $2$-form, $\Omega$.  When $k=2$, you could just define a scalar $W$ to be the ratio of $\gamma^*\Omega$ to the induced area form on $M^2$.  The formula is 
$$
W = \sum_{\alpha} h_{\alpha11}h_{\alpha22}-{h_{\alpha12}}^2
$$
This agrees with the Gauss-Kronecker curvature when $n=3$ and generalizes it when $n>3$.
When $n=2m$ and $k=n{-}2=2m{-}2$, you could take $L$ to be the scalar that is the ratio of 
$(\gamma^*\Omega)^{m-1}/((m{-}1)!)$ to the volume form on $M$.  Of course, $W$ and $L$ are the same when $(k,n) = (2,4)$.

Of course, $S$, $W$, and $L$ generally have different properties, even when they are all defined.  The good thing is that these things don't depend on a positive definite metric.  They'll work for any submanifold on which the first fundamental form is nondegenerate.

Comment: Isn't $W$, up to a constant factor, just the scalar curvature of $M$, at least in the case of Euclidean signature? Also, I am not entirely convinced by the last paragraph. Ideally the definition should be invariant under isometric transformations of the ambient space, but since your definitions use the $SO(n)$ invariant metric on the Grassmannian, this is in general not going to be preserved by $SO(1,n-1)$ actions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}_1$ for example. On the other hand, it seems natural to replace the Riemannian Grassmannian in your example directly by...

Comment: ... the space of all linear subspaces of a fixed signature in $\mathbb{R}^n_\nu$. You get a (non-compact in general) homogeneous space of the Lorentz group (or the $SO$ group of whatever the ambient signature is). If I am doing the math correctly then the $W$ defined relative to this group would indeed be just the scalar curvature. Though I am not too sure what $L$ would be in this case.

Comment: @WillieWong:  Of course, in my final sentence, I did *not* mean that you should use the $\mathrm{SO}(n)$-invariant metric!  I meant that there are analogs in the other signatures for the subsets of the Grassmannians that correspond to subspaces on which the inner product is nondegenerate.  Perhaps I should have inserted a *mutatis mutandis* in that sentence, but I assumed that this would be clear to the reader.

Comment: I had guessed that's what you meant. But considering the OP's background I think it would be worth making explicit.

Comment: @WillieWong:  You may be right about that.  Of course, you are also right that $W$ is the Gauss curvature of the induced metric, but my intended point was that the form $\Omega$ is a natural object that can be used in conduction with the Gauss map to make a construction that works in all codimensions (for surfaces) and can be used in codimension $2$ (in the even dimensional case) to define a different scalar invariant.  I just wanted to emphasize that there are several 'natural' constructions of scalar quantities from the second fundamental form.

Comment: To that sentiment I totally agree. (I wish I can give a separate additional +1 to your answer just for the first sentence!)

Comment: Nice explanation. I haven't said in the question what kinds of properties I wanted the curvature to have, because I simply don't know what to "want", I have a quite weak background so far. But yes, a scalar quantity which is a function of the second fundamental form is what I expected, somehow. Your answer made the point to me that I have some freedom to define these objects...
About the generalized Gauss map, I think I understood it fine. I'm not so familiar with group actions, though. About the ratio of volume forms, for a surface $M^2 \subset \Bbb R^4$, if I haven't got anything wrong...

Comment: ... I defined $$K = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\det(- {\rm d}{\bf N}_\theta)\,{\rm d}\theta,$$ where ${\bf N}_\theta = \cos \theta {\bf N}_1+\sin \theta{\bf N}_2$, and $\{{\bf N}_1,{\bf N}_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the normal space. With this definition, I have proved that $$K = \frac{\det(-{\rm d}{\bf N}_1)+\det(-{\rm d}{\bf N}_2)}{2},$$ and hence the curvature is the mean of these determinants for any orthonormal basis. I have also been told that a version of Gauss-Bonnet's theorem will hold (although I have no idea nor the means to get to it now). I think that this definition...

Comment: may be workable with, and I would like your opinion on it.. And thank you very much for the attention and the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just a remark about the n=4 case: one could proceed by analogy with the n=3 in which the Gauss-Kronecker curvature K happens to be equal to the curvature of the induced metric on the surface (intrinsic curvature). This is Gauss' famous *Teorema Egregium* (observe also that this still holds true, maybe up to sign, in the Lorentzian case). In the case of surfaces in 4-space, one could look for an expression of the second fundamental form which happens to be equal, again, to the intrinsic curvature of the surface. An examination of Gauss equation 
  $$ \langle R(X,Y)Z,W \rangle + \langle h(Y,Z) ,h(X,W)\rangle - \langle h(Y,W) ,h(X,Z) \rangle= 0$$ 
shows that this quantity will be
 $$ K(\nu_1) + K(\nu_2),$$
where $(\nu_1,\nu_2)$ is an orthonormal basis of the normal space and I follow
Deane Yang's notation. In other words, the average on unit vectors, as suggested Deane.

I don't see any generalization in higher dimension.